# Need assistance with regex

Tags: regex

For my regex, I want letters from a-z 1-4 times followed by any digit 4-7 times. The combination of these two should have 8 characters total. something like this

`([a-z]{1,4}[0-9]{4,7}){8}`

I know this is wrong. Can anyone tell me the right regex expression to make this work

Comment: Look, an honest attempt! +1! (You could also have added with what input it works/does not work.)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use a lookahead based regular expression to assert the string length is exactly eight characters.

```
^(?=.{8}$)[a-z]{1,4}\d{4,7}$
```

[Explanation](http://regexdoc.com/re/explain.pl?re=%5E%28%3F%3D.%7B8%7D%24%29%5Ba-z%5D%7B1%2C4%7D%5Cd%7B4%2C7%7D%24&.submit=Explain%21&mode=SO&.cgifields=mode) | [**Live Demo**](http://regex101.com/r/nB8bC8/2)

Comment: and what if i wanted text after the 8 characters....like "somthing"... would the lookahead be ^(?=.{8}something$)

Comment: example: dorv0015@algonquinlive.com... its a college email so I dont need to worry about anything after the 8 characters

Comment: and have the rest of that text following it(@algonquinlive.com)

Comment: except the .+ allows any number of characters... I need the college domain after those 8 characters

Comment: I figured it out based on the first 8...haha sorry about all the trouble

Comment: No worries. You did confuse me at first although. =)